# Форма отправляет данные, только при изменении первого инпута

Tags: php, html, form

Столкнулся с необъяснимой проблемой, уже долго сижу над этим вопросом.

Есть форма, которая обновляет данные в базе. Суть в том, что форма отправляет запрос, только в том случае, если был изменен первый input с названием. Если же изменять всё, но не трогать первый инпут, форма никуда не летит.

Буду рад любому напутственному слову.

```
    <?php
    include ROOT . '/view/layouts/header.php'; ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/view/css/crud.css">


    <div class="container update">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="main_form">

            <?php
                $selected = '';
                if($res):
                    ?>
                    <h3 class="success">Обновление успешно</h3>

                <?php
                else:
            ?>
            <h1>Изменение</h1>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 pr-0">
                    <label for="name">Название: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7">
                    <input class="w-100" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="<?=$book['name_book'] ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row_genre">
                <div class="col-4 pr-0">
                    <label for="genre[]">Жанр (зажав ctrl выбрать все жанры, которые соответствуют): </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <select name="genre[]" id="genre" multiple size="11">
                        <option value="1">Апокалиптика</option>
                        <option value="2">Боевые Искуства</option>
                        <option value="3">Детектив</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <textarea name="active_genre" id="active_genre" rows="4" readonly>Активные: <?=$book['genre']; ?></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 pr-0">
                    <label for="author">Автор: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7">
                    <input class="w-100" id="author" name="author" type="text" value="<?=$book['author'] ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 pr-0">
                    <label for="ongoing">Онгоинг </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7">
                    <select name="ongoing" id="ongoing">
                        <?php
                            if(!$book['ongoing'])
                                $selected = 'selected';
                        ?>
                        <option value="0" <?=$selected ?>>Нет</option>
                        <?php
                            $selected = '';
                            if($book['ongoing'])
                                $selected = 'selected';
                        ?>
                        <option value="1" <?=$selected ?>>Да</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 pr-0">
                    <label for="year">Год выхода: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7">
                    <input class="w-100" id="year" name="year" type="number" maxlength="4" value="<?=$book['b_year']?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 pr-0">
                    <label for="description">Описание: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7">
                    <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="<?=$book['b_description'] ?>"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7 offset-4">
                    <input  type="submit" name="saveUpdate" value="Сохранить изменения" class="btn btn-light w-100 mt-3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
            if($errors && !$res):
                ?>
                <ul class="col-3">
                        <li><?= $errors ?></li>
                </ul>

            <?php
            endif;
        ?>
    </div>

<?php
    include ROOT . '/view/layouts/footer.php'; 
?>
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему может такое случится:

- Форма может не отправляться, если есть атрибут pattern, и значение не удовлетворяет ему.
- Вы переопределяете в скрипте ajax событие submit. Если у вас есть условия для проверки с return, можно вылететь из скрипта.

Рабочий код:

```
<?php
    $book = array();
    if(isset($_POST["saveUpdate"])) {

        $book = array('name_book' => $_POST["name"], 'author' => $_POST["author"], 'b_year' => $_POST["year"] );
    }
    else
        $book = array('name_book' => "title", 'author' => "author", 'b_year' => 2019);

?>
<form action="#" method="post" id="main_form">
      <input class="w-100" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="<?=$book['name_book'] ?>">
      <input class="w-100" id="author" name="author" type="text" value="<?=$book['author'] ?>">
      <input class="w-100" id="year" name="year" type="number" maxlength="4" value="<?=$book['b_year']?>">
      <input  type="submit" name="saveUpdate" value="Сохранить изменения" class="btn btn-light w-100 mt-3">
</form>
```

Comment: Может ли это быть из-за того, что внутри скрипта-обработчика, есть функция, которая возвращает false?

Comment: @byNeznayka Возвращает false и вызывает прерывание скрипта? Т.е. записано так if(!your_function()) return;

Comment: Да, была проблема с return, был не до конца внимательным. Спасибо.